# Resource : Single location to multiple mappings

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, servlets, spring-mvc

When I use in my application:

```
<resources location="/resources/favicon.ico" mapping="/favicon.ico" />
```

to map out single resource.

How can I map single resource to be accessible through multiple mappings without need to duplicate the file locally ?

For example like this:

```
<resources location="/resources/favicon.ico" mapping="/favicon.ico" />
<resources location="/resources/favicon.ico" mapping="/favicon.png" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include wildcards. `mapping="/favicon.*"`

Comment: that's not too smart, but if it's only option, than thank you. I'm little bit disappointed, that such simple thing is not achievable in this system ... :(

Comment: what could be smarter than supporting wildcards? Your suggested solution would also work, but it's duplicating the resource definition

Comment: Problem is, my suggested solution is not working. Mapping is applied only for first time. Second mapping does not work at all. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: aha. Then the wildcard remains. Let me know if it worked. I've used it only with `/foo/**`

Comment: Ok. It works, but only in provided condition. In other cases, second and next mappings to single resource are ignored